# AWS Serverless Requests - JSON body / httpMethod is always null

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, http, aws-lambda

When I send POST request I am getting NullPointerException from **input.getBody()** and **input.getHttpMethod()**. I have no defined mapping template - It is set to **When no template matches the request Content-Type header** by default.

**My POST request**

```
{
    "shiftStart": "22/02/2021 18:00:00",
    "shiftEnd": "22/02/2021 19:00:00",
    "employee": {
        "id": "6",
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Brown"
    }
}
```

Once I got this exception so it looks like **input.getHttpMethod()** passed once:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "BODY",
    "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "stackTrace": [
        "helloworld.App.handleRequest(App.java:48)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
        "java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
    ]
}
```

but I did not changed anything and now I am getting following exception:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "stackTrace": [
        "helloworld.App.handleRequest(App.java:41)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
        "java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
    ]
}
```

**My classes:**

```
public class App implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input, final Context context) {

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("X-Custom-Header", "application/json");

        APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                .withHeaders(headers);

        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

        Shift shift;
        String output;

        if (input.getHttpMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.GET.name())) {
            shift = mapper.load(Shift.class, context.getAwsRequestId());
            if (shift == null) {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Resource not found");
            }
            output = shift.toString();
        } else if (input.getHttpMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.POST.name())) {
            if (input.getBody() == null) throw new NullPointerException("BODY");
            shift = new Shift(input.getBody());
            WorkSchedule workSchedule = new WorkSchedule(client);
            if (!workSchedule.isShiftPossible(shift)) {
                throw new ConditionalCheckFailedException("Conditional check failed");
            }
            mapper.save(shift);
            output = "SHIFT SAVED";
        } else {
            output = "Unsupported operation";
        }

        return response
                .withStatusCode(200)
                .withBody(output);
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "WORK_SCHEDULE")
public class Shift {

    public Shift(String json) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Shift request = gson.fromJson(json, Shift.class);
        this.id = request.getId();
        this.shiftStart = request.getShiftStart();
        this.shiftEnd = request.getShiftEnd();
        this.employee = request.getEmployee();
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String shiftStart;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String shiftEnd;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private Employee employee;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Shift{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", shiftStart='" + shiftStart + '\'' +
                ", shiftEnd='" + shiftEnd + '\'' +
                ", employee=" + employee +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Employee {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: you have enabled proxy integration in ApiGateway IntegrationRequest ?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I enabled this and my POST request is working now, but when I try to do GET request the response is : "message": "Internal server error". Can you check my GET if statement? - is it correct:   shift = mapper.load(Shift.class, context.getAwsRequestId());

Comment: Great!! Now for GET, ‘ context.getAwsRequestId()’ will only have a UUID generated by AWS. I am guessing you need something from path or query parameters, not this? They should be part of ‘input’  itself not ‘context’

Comment: @BaluVyamajala First I changed mapper.load(Shift.class, context.getAwsRequestId()); to  shift = mapper.load(Shift.class, input.getQueryStringParameters()); and then I changed   shift = mapper.load(Shift.class, input.getPathParameters());. Both of them give me "Internal server error".

Comment: can you print `input.toString()` and see if you are getting the parameter values as expected. Also getQueryStringParameters and getPathParameters  returns a Map, you probably need to fetch value and pass it to `mapper.load` ?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala i post answer with input.toString() content

Comment: ideally you should just updated your question with more details but not add more details as an aswer.  `input.getPathParameters().get("id")` should give you the Dynamo Autogenerated id from path params and  it should be `mapper.load(Shift.class, input.getPathParameters().get("id"))`

Comment: unfortunately mapper.load(Shift.class, input.getPathParameters().get("id")) is not working too

Comment: @BaluVyamajala do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: we need print and look at cloudwatch logs. i can't spot any specific issue with GET.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I edited post and added cloudwatch logs for GET request. You need to open image to see better.

Comment: I managed with it. @NoArgsConstructor lombok annotation was missing in Employee class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Api Gateway has two basic types of Lambda integration LAMBDA AND LAMBDA_PROXY.

Regular LAMBDA will just pass through request body as is.

If we enable `Use Lambda Proxy integration` in integration request, it will be LAMBDA_PROXY and this will pass through the request by wrapping additional details like queryParms, Api Keys, Http Headers, method type, etc. which can be serialized into `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` class.

`queryStringParameters` with queryParms.

`body` with Json body as string.

`pathParameters` with Path Parameters.

So, in this case, we just need to enable `Use Lambda Proxy integration`